# Drawing big circles from scratch

Tags: c++, graphics, drawing, 2d, geometry

I am new to C++, but the language seems alright to me. As a learning project I have decided to make a minor 2D graphic-engine. It might seem like a hard project, but I have a good idea how to move on.

I havn't really started yet, but I am forming things in my head at the moment, when I came across this problem:
At some point I will have to make a function to draw circles on the screen. My approach to that right now would be something like this:

```
in a square with sides from (x-r) to (x+r) loop through x and y,
if at each point, the current distance sqr(x^2+y^2) is less than or equal to r
, then draw a pixel at that point.
```

This would work, if not, dont bother telling me, I'll figure it out. I would of cause only draw this circle if the x+r & y+r is on the screen.

The problem lies in that I will need to draw really big circles sometimes. If for example I need to draw a circle with radius 5000, the (if pixel loop calculations would need loop a total of 10000^2 times). So with a processor at 2Ghz, this single circle would only be able to render 2Ghz/(10000^2) which is ~22 times/s while taking up the whole core (believing it only takes one calculation per pixel, which is nowhere the truth).

Which approach is the correct one now? I guess it has something to do with using the GFX for these simple calculations. If so, can I use OpenGL for C++ for this? I'd like to learn that as well :)

Comment: [Midpoint circle algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midpoint_circle_algorithm)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My first C/C++ projects were in fact graphics libraries as well. I did not have OpenGL or DirectX and was using DOS at the time. I learned quite a lot from it, as I constantly found new and better (and faster) ways to draw to the screen.

The problem with modern operating systems is that they don't really allow you to do what I did back then. You cannot just start using the hardware directly. And frankly, these days you don't want to anymore.

You can still draw everything yourself. Have a look at SDL if you want to put your own pixels. This is a C library that you will be able to wrap into your own C++ objects. It works on different platforms (including Linux, Windows, Mac,...) and internally it will make use of things like DirectX or OpenGL.

For real-world graphics, one doesn't just go about drawing one's own pixels. That is not efficient. Or at least not on devices where you cannot use the hardware directly...

But for your purposes, I think SDL is definitely the way to go! Good luck with that.

Comment: "one doesn't just go about drawing one's own pixels. That is not efficient" <- Sometimes "drawing your own pixels" is more efficient than making GPU do it. Because for example with OpenGL you need to create a context which takes ~400ms or more. For example i doubt that this site's autogenerated random avatars uses OpenGL or DirectX to render them (that would be stupid, to buy a GFX card just for that). Also i wouldnt trust the stability or compatibility of a GFX card that much either. With CPU you know it will work.

Comment: Well yes, but not for drawing filled circles with a radius of 5000 pixels, right?! That is the question. And with that in mind, there are more efficient ways than to draw pixels one-by-one.

Comment: Great, fast response! Thank you

I actually do use SDL already, I should've said so, but I dont really know exactly what it is just yet. I just downloaded it because Google told me so. I will deffinetely read more into it.

Comment: So, am I right to believe SDL talks with OpenGL, but makes it work as a 2D environment? Are there functions in SDL to draw filled triangles instead of working on a per-pixel basis?

Comment: SDL will indeed talk to OpenGL when available. It will be 2D. And as far as I know, there is nothing to draw filled triangles, there are filled rectangles though... Check http://wiki.libsdl.org/moin.cgi/APIByCategory (choose Video)

Comment: @Koder, Perhaps, but even that can be optimized, and it wont really be that slow as you think. writing 5000px diameter circle amount of pixels doesnt take that much time. it might even be as fast as with OpenGL, or faster. The time it uses is wasted on the simple buffer copy/paste operations, which the CPU based circle filling algorithm wouldnt have, but it would also do the same pixel writing, actually less of writing since it skips writing the outsides of the circle. OpenGL version would need to copy the pixels to larger image. If i had the fastest circle filling algo, i would just test it.

Answer (score 2):

You don't do graphics by manually drawing pixels to screen, that way madness lies.

What you want to use is either DirectX or OpenGL. I suggest you crack open google and go read, there's a lot to read out there.

Once you've downloaded the libs there's lots of sample projects to take a look at, they'll get you started.

There's two approaches at this point: there's the mathematical way of calculating the vectors that describe a shape with a very large number of sides (i.e it'll look like a circle). Or there's the 'cheating' method of just drawing a texture (i.e a picture) of a circle to the screen with an alpha channel to make the rest of the texture transparent. (The cheating method is easier to code, faster to execute, and produces a better result, although it is less flexible).

If you want to do it mathematically then both of these libraries will allow you to draw lines to screen, so you need to begin your approach from the view of start point and end point of each line, not the individual pixels. i,e you want vector graphics.

I can't do the heavy maths right now, but the vector approach might look a little like this (sudo-code):

```
in-param: num_of_sides, length_of_side;
float angle = 360 / num_of_sides;
float start_x = 0;
float start_y = 0;

x = startX;
y = startX;
for(int i(0); i < num_of_sides; ++i)
{
  float endX, endY;
  rotateOffsetByAngle(x, y, x + lenth_of_side, y, angle * i, endX, endY);
  drawline(x, y, endX, endY);
  x = endX;
  y = endY;
}


drawline(float startX, startY, endX, endY)
{
  //does code that draws line between the start and end coordinates;
}

rotateOffsetByAngle(float startX, startY, endX, endY, angle, &outX, &outY)
{
  //the in-parameters startX, startY and endX, endY describe a line
  //we treat this line as the offset from the starting point

  //do code that rotates this line around the point startX, startY, by the angle.
  //after this rotation is done endX and endY are now at the same
  //distance from startX and startY that they were, but rotated.

  outX = endX;
  outY = endY; //pass these new coordinates back out by reference;

}
```

In the above code we move around the outside of the circle drawing each individual line around the outside 1 by one. For each line we have a start point and an offset, we then rotate the offset by an angle (this angle increases as we move around the circle). Then we draw the line from the start point to the offset point. Before we begin the next iteration we move the start point to the offset point so the next line starts from the end of the last.

I hope that's understandable.

Comment: The op asks because he wants to code it as a learning project (as I understood him). I think there is nothing wrong with doing something as basic as drawing a circle pixel-by-pixel to get used to programming...

Comment: "manually drawing pixels" isn't that bad thing as you make it sound. Sometimes you dont want, or you cant use GL/DX. There can be multiple reasons why.

Comment: @philip yeah you're right. I just saw his O(n2) method and knee-jerked it a little. The message I'd hope he gets from my answer is that drawing lines is the better approach. I've since added some sudo-code covering a (fairly poor I'll admit) method of using lines to draw a circle, but I intentionally left the actually drawing bit blank.

Answer (score 1):

That is one way to draw a filled circle. It will perform appallingly slowly, as you can see.

Modern graphics is based on abstracting away the lower-level stuff so that it can be optimised; the developer writes drawCircle(x,y,r) and the graphics libary + drivers can pass that all the way down to the chip, which can fill in the appropriate pixels.

Although you are writing in C++, you are not manipulating data closest to the core unless you use the graphics drivers. There are layers of subroutine calls between even your setPixelColour level methods and an actual binary value being passed over the wire; at almost every layer there are checks and additional calculations and routines run. The secret to faster graphics, then, is to reduce the number of these calls you make. If you can get the command drawCircle all the way to the graphics chip, do that. Don't waste a call on a single pixel, when it's as mundane as drawing a regular shape.

In a modern OS, there are layers of graphics processing taking the requests of individual applications like yours and combining them with the windowing, compositing and any other effects. So your command to 'draw to screen' is intermediated by several layers already. What you want to provide to the CPU is the minimum information necessary to offload the calculations to the graphics subsystem.

I would say if you want to learn to draw stuff on the screen, play with canvas and js, as the development cycle is easy and comparatively painless. If you want to learn C++, try project Euler, or draw stuff using existing graphics libraries. If you want to write a 2d graphics library, learn the underlying graphics technologies like DirectX and OpenGL, because they are the way that graphics is done in reality. But they seem so complex, you say? Then you need to learn more C++ first. They are the way they are for some very good reasons, however complex the result is.

Comment: Great read as well, thank you :)

I have no problem with OpenGL, i deffenetely want to learn it very soon, but at first look it didn't seem that great for 2D.

Answer (score 1):

As the first answer says, you shouldn't do this yourself for serious work. But if you just want to do this as an example, then could could do something like this: First define a function for drawing line segments on the screen:

```
void draw_line(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2);
```

This should be relatively straightforward to implement: Just find the direction that is changing fastest, and iterate over that direction while using integer logic to find out how much the other dimension should change. I.e., if x is changing faster, then `y = (x-x1)*(y2-y1)/(x2-x1)`.

Then use this function to implement a circle as piecewise line elements:

```
void draw_circle(int x, int y, int r)
{
    double dtheta = 2*M_PI/8/r;
    int x1 = x+r, x2, y1 = y, y2;
    int n = 2*M_PI/dtheta;
    for(int i = 1; i < n; i++)
    {
        double theta = i*dtheta;
        x2 = int(x+r*cos(theta)); y2 = int(y+r*sin(theta));
        draw_line(x1, y1, x2, y2);
        x1 = x2; y1 = y2;
    }
}
```

This uses floating point logic and trigonometric functions to figure out which line elements best approximate a circle. It is a somewhat crude implementation, but I think any implementation that wants to be efficient for very large circles has to do something like this.

If you are only allowed to use integer logic, one approach could be to first draw a low-resolution integer circle, and then subdivide each selected pixel into smaller pixels, and choose the sub-pixels you want there, and so on. This would scale as N log N, so still slower than the approach above. But you would be able to avoid sin and cos.

Comment: I must say that i'm not happy with the way you abuse the for loop. It might look good in theory, but you have to know floats/doubles are not precise, and with addition the precision is lost even more. Use multiplication, and ints for the loops.

Comment: You are right that this implementation is accumulating floating point errors by continuously incrementing theta as a floating point operation. However, this error is totally negligible in this case. But I'll rewrite it anyway.